# NSKeyedUnarchiver Warnings since iOS 15

Tags: swift, mapbox, nskeyedunarchiver

Since iOS 15 I keep getting warnings like those beyond. Only framework I'm using is Mapbox. Is there a workaround or fix?

```
2021-10-13 10:03:39.530114+0200 DemoApp[2661:532530] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSNumber' (0x1dcadbe40) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.objects', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDictionary' (0x1dcad0c28) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.
2021-10-13 10:03:39.530315+0200 DemoApp[2661:532530] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x1dcadb6e8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.objects', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDictionary' (0x1dcad0c28) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.
2021-10-13 10:03:39.530365+0200 DemoApp[2661:532530] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x1dcadb6e8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.objects', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDictionary' (0x1dcad0c28) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.
```

Comment: If you don't control the files that are written/write to the `plist` no you can't do anything about it the people that control them will likely issue an update. If you do control those files you have to have those struct/class conform to NSSecureCoding

Comment: I'm also seeing this in a project that includes Firebase. We need to wait update for pods.

Comment: any solution for this warning? please update

Comment: Nope, still waiting for any update myself and keep getting these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code (or library) you must have a call to NSKeyedUnarchiver that looks like:

> if let yourObject = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: yourclass.self,
> from: dataVariable) {
> }

Your 'yourClass' contains a String object that must be explicitly allowed, so change your code to:

> if let yourObject = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses:
> [YourClass.self, NSString.self], from: dataVariable) as? YourClass { }